# Why is blender physics bake slowing down after a couple of bakes?

Tags: physics, baking

When I'd do the first bake on my project the bake would literally go zip... done, but after a few bakes the bake time would go to a few minutes instead, and without adjustments.. Does the program start to iterate bakes after a couple of bakes? But if I create a new file and bake it again the bake goes zip again.

(*By zip I mean exaggeratively mean instantaneous*)